# How to pivot table without typing column name manually in SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I was trying to use pivot for 30 columns, I don't want to do it by typing manually, could anyone help me on that.
For example, I have some data like this

```
1   10000   may
1   400     july
2   4500    Jan
2   35000   Apri
1   5000    Feb
1   3000    Sep
2   200     Feb
2   90500   Oct
1   6000    Mar
1   5000    Mar
2   2500    Nov
```

My desired result would be like this.

```
empid  Apri   Feb   Jan   july  Mar     may     Nov     Oct     Sep
1      NULL   5000  NULL  400   6000    10000   NULL    NULL    3000
2      3500   200   4500  NULL  NULL    NULL    2500    90500   NULL
```

appreciate if you could give a hint.

Comment: You'll have to use a dynamic pivot, if you don't want to type them out. But if it's static, then i suggest doing the typing; don't be lazy.

Comment: Speaking of which, if you really can't be bothered typing but have static list, you can copy the column names out of a query, something like `SELECT STRING_AGG(val, ', ') FROM (SELECT DISTINCT val = QUOTENAME(values) FROM table) t`

Comment: @Charlieface Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could transfer all distinct month into XML, then use it in pivot

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(c.month)
            FROM #monthly_sales c
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,' ')

set @query = 'SELECT empid, ' + @cols + ' from 
            (
                select empid
                    , amount
                    , month
                from #Monthly_sales
           ) x
            pivot 
            (
                 max(amount)
                for month in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '
EXEC (@query)
```

Comment: Better to use `STRING_AGG` if on SQL 2017+

Comment: Thank you @Charlieface, that's very good to know.